# How many distinct species are seen in the Mos Eisley cantina?

Tags: star-wars

Granted, some of them are obvious (Wookiees, humans, etc), but what about all of the others? Greedo's race for example, and even the ones that are only shown but never speak.

Comment: [It does vary](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Which one?  Original theatrical, home video, special edition, 3D?  I'm sure there's some variances.

Comment: "Greedo's race" is Rodian...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a running list of the species seen in the Cantina as of the 2019 4K edition of *A New Hope*. (This excludes species seen in Chalmun's cantina in other works, such as *The Mandalorian*.)

- Abyssin ([Myo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Myo))
- Advozse ([Bom Vimdin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bom_Vimdin))
- Aqualish ([Ponda Baba](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ponda_Baba))
- Arcona ([Hem Dazon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hem_Dazon))
- Bimm ([Rycar Ryjerd](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rycar_Ryjerd))
- Bith ([Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Figrin_D%27an_and_the_Modal_Nodes))
- Chadra-Fan ([Kabe](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kabe))
- Defel ([Arleil Schous](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Arleil_Schous))
- Devaronian ([Kardue'sai'Malloc](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kardue%27sai%27Malloc))
- Duros ([Chachi De Maal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Baniss_Keeg), [Ohwun De Maal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ohwun_De_Maal))
- Givin ([Elis Helrot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Elis_Helrot))
- Gotal ([Feltipern Trevagg](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Feltipern_Trevagg))
- H'nemthe ([Mi'iiyoom Onith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/M%27iiyoom_Onith))
- Human ([BoShek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/BoShek), [Dr. Evazan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cornelius_Evazan), [Obi-Wan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Obi-Wan_Kenobi), [Garouf Lafoe](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Garouf_Lafoe), [Luke](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker), [Han Solo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo), [Wuher](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wuher))
- Ithorian ([Momaw Nadon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Momaw_Nadon))
- Jawa ([Het Nkik](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Het_Nkik))
- Lamproid ([Dice Ibegon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dice_Ibegon))
- Lutrillian ([Ownellco](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ownellco))
- Morseerian ([Nabrun Leids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nabrun_Leids))
- Nimbanel ([Mosep Binneed](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mosep_Binneed))
- Pacithhip ([Ketwol](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ketwol), post-1997 releases only)
- Qiraash ([Leesub Sirln](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leesub_Sirln))
- Ranat ([Reegesk](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Reegesk), named in Legends)
- Rodian ([Greedo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Greedo))
- Sakiyan ([Djas Puhr](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Djas_Puhr))
- Sarkan ([Melas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Melas), post-1997 releases only)
- Saurin ([Hrchek Kal Fas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hrchek_Kal_Fas), [Sai'torr Kal Fas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sai%27torr_Kal_Fas))
- Shistavanen ([Lak Sivrak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lak_Sivrak), pre-1997 releases only)
- Siniteen ([Pons Limbic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pons_Limbic))
- Stennes Shifter ([Bracconor Bakiska](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Braconnor_Bakiska))
- Talz ([Muftak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Muftak))
- Wookiee ([Chewbacca](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chewbacca))
- Yam'rii ([Kitik Keed'kak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kitik_Keed%27kak), named in Legends)

This adds up to **33 species**, although releases starting at the 1997 special edition replace shots of Lak Sivrak with the new characters Ketwol and Melas, so within a single edition of the film, only 31 or 32 species are seen.

Comment: You missed Han Solo

Comment: I seem to recall (maybe in a  statement by George Lucas) that the people in the galaxy far away aren't actually human?

Comment: @DannyMcG They're human according to C-3PO: "Don't worry about Master Luke. I'm sure he'll be all right. He's quite clever, you know... for a human being."

Comment: @Valorum To be fair, so did Greedo.

Comment: @DannyMcG - Asked and answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/are-the-humans-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-really-humans). In short, humans in the Star Wars universe are anatomically identical to Earth humans, but unrelated.